# Reading a variable length data, on Motorola FR terminal

Tags: c#, mobile, barcode-scanner, gs1-128, gs1-ai-syntax

Question is regarding a reading a EAN 128 variable length bar code from RF terminal to a SAP web application.

I have a EAN 128 bar code in this format: (02)93858881222369(10)20212(37)104, when you scan the code with a scanner, the fr terminal read a code like this: 02938588812223691020212?37104, you can see a FNC character "?" that represent a variable length filed, we predefined in SAP that AI is "?" The problem is when we scan the bar code and transfer scanned data to SAP app into the text field we get this:  0293858881222369102021237104, data without the AI, I researched the internet and found out that the scanner does NOT forward the non-ascii values in a bar code, so we have a problem.

Is there a way to bypass this or some kind of other solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. We work with similar situations. Usually most of all scanners can be adjusted, to process AIM codes, several barcode types, etc....if You can find the set up doc, you can adjust the scanner. But, if the ? represents a variable length field, which is meant ?

Comment: I know there is a way to adjust the scanner, but I didn't found how, I trided an option "Search and replace" but when I paste a barcode to plain text the FNC charater become a square

Comment: Vendor and Model of the scanner ? 

BTW: Use several editors, to paste the string. You might even find a homepage, which is able to parse by flagging some options. Like parse ASCII directly, or print unprintable symbols as ASCII-Code insteade, etc...

Comment: The scanner is a Motorola Omnii XT15f, My idea is to modify the scanned data and then send it to a field, I cannot modify the field on SAP app, only the scanned data, I know there is a way to reprogram scanner but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Ok, before placing the scanned string on ui fields,  you surely capture it inside a background abap program, how does it look like there,  in the debugger?

Comment: It's a closed platform, only i can see that delimiter is SAP is set to a "?" symbol, that's all I can see

Comment: You cannot debug the abap code? You need to.... How does it them come to the SAP at all? Webservice, whatever??? SICF...

Comment: I'm not a programmer, i'm consultant, only I can see that the scanner passe data to a SAP app in this format 0293858881222369102021237104, the data in the filed is in this format.

Comment: Then ask a developer there

Comment: I solved the problem, I reprogrammed RF terminal, the FNC character is in XEX format 0x1d, in RF terminal you have to input this in a case in format  and make a substitute with a desired characte \001d

Comment: You mean hex format. Anyway,  good for You. Have fun.